# Elastic search get all records for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I have two separate objects `authors` and `publishers`. How can I use elasticsearch to get all of both types?

I know I can do the following to search both:

```
Elasticsearch::Model.search('foo', [Author, Publisher])
```

But how do I get that to return all records?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, misread the question in my original answer.

To match all documents do:

```
response = Elasticsearch::Model.search('{ "query": { "match_all": {} } }', [Author, Publisher])
```

Comment: This doesn't help. I too can read the documentation. This searches for "fox". I am looking for ALL records.